# Problems with the screen

Tags: 12.04, screen

I've just installed 12.04 LTS on my laptop and I'm having some problems with the screen.

Whenever I change from a window to another, the screen seems like it had stripes; but after two or three seconds, it works in a normal way.

The same thing happens when I'm writing on the keyboard happens, so I can't see if I'm writing right or not.

I've tried to install the additional controllers that appear on the system configuration menu, but when I click on the activate, after a minute or so appears a message saying:

```
We are sorry, the installation of the driver failed:
Check  the log to see the details:/var/log/jockey.log.
```

There are two additional controllers:

1. FGLRX propietary graphics driver for ATI/AMD (post-release updates)
2. FGLRX propietary graphics driver for ATI/AMD

My computer is a Toshiba Satellite L850-150.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Install the *2nd* driver, as I believe the post release updates **aren't supported** anymore. If that doesn't work, **manually install** them:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`

`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-upadtes`

Restart. Then:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install fglrx* fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev`

`sudo aticonfig --initial`

Restart, and the drivers should be installed.

### Double check:

`fglrxinfo`

...And if it outputs something like:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: thank you!
this solved the problem, but just when I'm using batery, when I remove it, and plug only the charger, it doesn,t work.
What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what could be causing that. You can always download the latest drivers from AMDs homepage, though I haven't tried this before, remove the drivers you installed before through the commands in my previous answer, then run `sudo sh [driver].run` replacing [driver] with the name of the driver.